# FB.ui share_open_graph strange dialog behaviour

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to implement URL sharing on Facebook via javascript, sharing also a  picture.
When the FB sharing dialog appears, it starts shrinking itself and keeps shrinking more and more until it becomes about 20 pixels wide.

And it happens using either the share_open_graph or "share" method.

Also, on the JS console i see this error when the sharing dialog appears:

```
ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Could not find element \"%s\"%s 
from module \"%s\"","u_0_18","","__el...". 
Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

This is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
            FB.init({
                appId: '476337039102253',
                version: 'v2.8'
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(APP.fbUpdateStatusCallback);

        });            
});
</script>

<button id="itb" class="btn btn-primary btn-large active_down" name="btn" onclick="
            FB.ui({
                method: 'share_open_graph',
                action_type: 'og.shares',
                action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                    object: {
                        'og:url': 'https://example.com',
                        'og:title': 'page title',
                        'og:description': 'desc',
                        'og:image': 'https://savebybooking.s3.amazonaws.com/public/prd/File_341'
                    }
                })             
            }, function(response){
                if (response &amp;&amp; !response.error_message) {
                  console.log('fb sharing OK: '+JSON.stringify(response));
                } else {
                 console.log('Not OK: '+JSON.stringify(response));
                }
           }); return false;" type="submit">Share</button>
```

Are you having the same issue? Why is it happening?
I used the "share" method until yesterday without problems,  this issue appeared today with no modification to my code.

p.s. I prefer 
    using share_open_graph
rather than
    share
method because the latter won't let you share the specified picture but seems to pick a random image from the url you are sharing.

Comment: We just started seeing this error in the last 24 hours or so. I don't think it's a result of our code; my hunch is it's a bug on facebook's side.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug to the fb developer center: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/349376535505059/

Comment: Any follow up on this yet?

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu The bug is still there for me. How about you ?

Comment: @Pixel I saw it yesterday again, but have not been able to reproduce it or find a pattern.

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu On my site the bug reproduces every single time the "facebook share" div opens up. For you just once in a while? We may want to use lower level FB apis to make the calls to FB,  and we manually build the div html. Is it possible?

Comment: got the same error today myself, no code change on my side...never experienced it before though

Answer (score 0):

This is the error inside of the FB dialog, not inside the page launching the dialog. Also it's because you're missing the meta tags on the page you're sharing. Nothing for FB to scrape for your share.